# Wrong monthly lineplot using seaborn, pandas and datetime

Tags: python, pandas, seaborn

I am trying to create the following diagram, but with the written months as xticks instead of the integer:

[image: Almost right]

My code currently looks like this:

```
plt.figure(figsize=(10,5))
sns.lineplot(x="Month",y="DHN",data = df.head(1100),color="BLACK")
sns.lineplot(x="Month",y="Heat Loss",data = df.head(1100),color ="RED")
```

Which results in:

[image]

Obviously, multiple things are wrong with this diagram. The Diagram x axis should start with January, the values inside the dataframe are getting stacked for the months (?) and the scale for `df.head(1100)` should not inclued months like december or september.

The first lines of the Dataframe look like this:

[image]

with Date as datetime.

What am I missing that it's not working out the way I want it to?

Answer (score 5):

Convert `Month` column to `ordered categorical`s for correct ordering values in axis x in ploting:

```
cats = ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr','May', 'Jun', 'Jul', 'Aug', 'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec']
df['Month'] = pd.Categorical(df['Month'], ordered=True, categories=cats)

plt.figure(figsize=(10,5))
sns.lineplot(x="Month",y="DHN",data = df.head(1100),color="BLACK")
sns.lineplot(x="Month",y="Heat Loss",data = df.head(1100),color ="RED")
```

**Sample**:

```
np.random.seed(123)

def random_dates(start, end, n=100):

    start_u = start.value//10**9
    end_u = end.value//10**9

    return pd.to_datetime(np.random.randint(start_u, end_u, n), unit='s')

start = pd.to_datetime('2015-01-01')
end = pd.to_datetime('2017-01-20')
df = pd.DataFrame({'Date':random_dates(start, end),
                   'DHN':np.random.randint(500, size=100),
                   'Heat Loss':np.random.randint(50, size=100)})
df['Month'] = df['Date'].dt.strftime('%b')
df = df.sort_values('Date')
print (df.head())

                  Date  DHN  Heat Loss Month
55 2015-01-07 20:29:22  296         23   Jan
29 2015-01-08 13:49:04  486         18   Jan
36 2015-01-15 23:32:55  294          9   Jan
59 2015-01-19 10:33:39  256          5   Jan
72 2015-01-19 19:48:43  254          3   Jan
```

---

```
cats = ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr','May', 'Jun', 'Jul', 'Aug', 'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec']
df['Month'] = pd.Categorical(df['Month'], ordered=True, categories=cats)

plt.figure(figsize=(10,5))
sns.lineplot(x="Month",y="DHN",data = df.head(1100),color="BLACK")
sns.lineplot(x="Month",y="Heat Loss",data = df.head(1100),color ="RED")
```

[image: graph]

Comment: when I plot over the whole df (not .head()) I lose data resolution of the graph. Peaks between months are flatten out. Seems like data points between lets say Jan and Feb are left out?

Comment: @Phil it is possible, best test data if not rows with some months missing.

Comment: the data isnt missing in the df tho!

Comment: @Phil - Is possible share data if not confidental?

Comment: can't share it sorry. But creating a random df with values for each hour of the year should make it possible to give hints on what is wrong with my code i guess.

Comment: @Phil - hmmm, so is possible share only `Date` column like `df[['Date']].to_csv(file, index=False)`?

Comment: pretty unspectacular. Just every hour from 1.1.17 to 31.12.17

Comment: @Phil so problem is no data or data too small like another in some months, so seems like 0 data? Or something else?